# Replicating Standard tabs in Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable, tab, table

I have come up against a wall and I am hoping my options are not as bleak as they seem...

I am trying to create a simply list view on a visualforce page. I am not requiring assistance with any coding so I am not going to post any; instead I simply need an answer to this question:

I want to consume a list object in an apex class, which specifically is a list of opportunities that meet a specific set of criteria. I then wish to display these records in a visualforce table of sorts (not fussed which table type is used) and limit the number of rows per page ie set it to 20 and there will be a next and previous button like the enhanced table.

Th wall I have hit is that normal table elements like page block table do not allow the limiting of rows per page, and require heavy javascript/jquery (especially if you wish to implement sorting via letter etc) and the enhanced list view only accepts entire objects and do not work with a list object from an apex class. Is my understanding correct? If so, is there a solution other than jquery tabs?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options. You can either use offset in SOQL query and build a custom pagination. You can give offset values up to 2000. Or using stadnardsetcontroller you can build a pagination which allows you to paginate up to 10k records. Please check the link below,
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Paginating_Data_for_Force.com_Applications

You can add sorting in both of these pagination with additional coding.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you could do that by using the list to construct a StandardSetController and then use the setPageSize, next, and previous methods for your pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be answering my own question - I actually came up with a solution in the mean time and simply if anyone comes across this here is my solution:

Using the enhancedList element you can customise the filtering. Simply create a list view on the object and then specify the list view ID in the ListId parameter on the enhanced list element. In my example below, I have put my IDs into custom labels for deployment sake.

**Visualforce page:**

```
<style>
    .controls{
        display:none;
    }
</style>

<apex:form >
    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedView}" size="1" multiselect="false" styleClass="viewSelect" style="min-width: 200px;padding: 4px 6px;margin: 4px 5px 4px 0px;font-weight: bold;">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="tableArea" status="searchStatus" />
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Views}" />
    </apex:selectList>
    <apex:actionStatus id="searchStatus"><apex:facet name="start">Loading...</apex:facet></apex:actionStatus>
</apex:form>

<apex:outputPanel id="tableArea">
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(selectedView == 'All', true, false)}">
        <apex:enhancedlist type="Opportunity" height="730" customizable="false" rowsPerPage="25" Listid="{!$Label.TAB_Opportunities}" />
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(selectedView == 'My', true, false)}">
        <apex:enhancedlist type="Opportunity" height="730" customizable="false" rowsPerPage="25" Listid="{!$Label.TAB_My_Opportunities}" />
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(selectedView == 'Open', true, false)}">
        <apex:enhancedlist type="Opportunity" height="730" customizable="false" rowsPerPage="25" Listid="{!$Label.TAB_Open_Opportunities}" />
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

**Apex Class:**

```
public class opportunityTab{
public String selectedView {get;set;}
public opportunityTab(){
selectedView = 'All';
}
public List getViews() {
List options = new List();
options.add(new SelectOption('All','All Opportunities'));
options.add(new SelectOption('My','My Opportunities'));
options.add(new SelectOption('Open','Open Opportunities'));
return options;
}
}
```